# Uncheck Checkbox inputs in Clojurescript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I have a series of checkbox inputs and I'd like to uncheck all the boxes when the user clicks a button.  Checking the inputs doesn't seem to set an attr, so I'm unsure if/how to reset the "checked" prop.  I'd like to do this in pure CLJS, no extra DOM manipulation libraries, please.  If there is a smarter way to do this within the Reagent framework, that would also be an acceptable/helpful answer.

```
(defn clear-order []
  (map #(set! (.-checked %) false) (.getElementsByTagName js/document "input")))
```

This gets all my inputs, and maybe does what it's supposed to, but doesn't actually uncheck my inputs.

Comment: `map` is lazy. it doesnt't execute the function until the element is needed. Just use `run!` instead, https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run! (or also `doseq`, `dorun`, `doall`)

Comment: Swapping `map` for `run!` yields `Uncaught Error: [object HTMLCollection] is not ISeqable`.

Comment: well, it means it is not sequable.. maybe this could help: https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-2084?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like someone said in a comment, you need to use something eager and not `map`, which is lazy. `run!` is like an eager `map`. Also `HTMLCollection`s aren't seqable, so you can use `goog.array/toArray` to get something that is.

Putting that together:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require
   [goog.array :as garray]))

(defn clear-order []
  (run! #(set! (.-checked %) false)
        (garray/toArray (.getElementsByTagName js/document "input"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(doseq [something (goog.array.toArray (.getElementsByTagName js/document "input"))]
         (js/console.log something))
```